# How can I retrieve current Autofac lifecyclescope and resolve nested forms in a Winform app

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, inversion-of-control, autofac

I have a Winforms application that uses Autofac for IoC/DI

I have setup the autofac configuration so all forms can be resolved through the container/LCS.

I want to inject each Winforms related services through constructor injection.

So in my app program I create the container and a root lifecyclescope and resolve the main form:

```
using (Autofac.IContainer container = Startup.Autofac.Initialize())
{
    FormFactory winfactory = FormFactory.Init(container);
    var form = FormFactory.CreateForm<Form1>();
    Application.Run(form);
}
```

This works as expected, and my services get injected fine.

Now a user interaction on the main form requires a new detail form to be opened. So the main form needs to resolve and show the detail form. I would like to do this on the current lifetimescope of the mainform, but I don't know how to get a reference to it!

In MVC it seems bundled into the MVC/Autofac integration in the Nuget packages, using DependencyResolver.Current. But this is not available outside MVC applications.

Can anyone be so kind to provide me with some help on this and eventually some best practices on resolving nested forms in a Winforms application?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no formal integration for Autofac in a Winforms app. There's no built-in concept of request/response or "request lifecycle" in a Winforms app. Winforms is stateful and integration into the app is on a per-app basis.

What that means - and I know this isn't going to be the answer you want, but it *is* the answer - is that **you have to write the Autofac integration into your custom Winforms app**.

You may need to add the [Microsoft CommonServiceLocator package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommonServiceLocator/) into your app, which basically provides the `DependencyResolver` implementation for generic app types. [Autofac has integration with CommonServiceLocator.](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/csl.html)

However, keep in mind that Autofac tracks disposables (`IDisposable` implementations) so if you're resolving things right out of the root container you could encounter a memory leak - the disposables resolved from the root container, by default, won't be disposed *until you dispose of the container*. [There is documentation on controlling scope and lifetime for components.](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/index.html)

What that means is you'll want to create Autofac lifetime scopes and resolve from those, disposing the child scopes to clean up. That's how MVC-style per-request lifetimes work ([and there's doc on that, too](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html)).

Beyond that, **there's no "best practice" or "guidance" that I can provide.** There's no composition root - no built-in DI hooks - in Winforms, so it really, truly is *app-specific*. I can't say if something is "good" or "recommended" for your app. I can't say if something "isn't good" or is "bad practice." It's all app-specific and you're going to have to do that leg-work.

Comment: Thanks a lot Travis for your advice on this matter. But less great news than I would have hoped for...
It is unfortunatly very difficult to find some decent advice on how to integrate Autofac correct into Winform Apps. It's a pity as it's a place you need to be expert on IoC and Autofac to make sure you're not introducing memoryleaks or aplly wrong patterns with poor performance as a result.  But I'll take a look at the CommonServiceLocator package as you suggest. Thanks again..